# Angular 4 Router - Hook each router changes

Tags: angular, service, breadcrumbs, angular4-router

I would like to create a `Breadcrumb`.

[Breadcrumb Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_(navigation))

And for this, I thought about creating a Service to handle it. But I need to hook each router changes, a method or a class that will be used everytime the router state change.

This challenge have to be resolved without adding a onActivate method in all my components because I have a lot of them.

Great thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular 7 made the `events` into an `Observable`, so you'll need to use different code to filter for the `NavigationEnd` event.

```js
class MyService {
  constructor(public router: Router, logger: Logger) {
    router.events
      .pipe(filter(e => e instanceof RouterEvent))
      .subscribe(e => {
        logger.log(e.id, e.url);
      });
  }
}
```

See https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent for details.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [Router events](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#events) to track route changes

```js
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

class MyService {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events
      .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe(e => console.log('Route changed: ' + e.url);

  }

}
```